# Mysql Java update column from jtextfield

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

How to update a field in my database from a `JTextField` using java?

- My field in the data base: `total`
- My field in java: `add_quantity`

I need to add the quantity to the total, using sql.

```
total = total + add_quantity
```

I tried this:

```
String value1 = jTextField5.getText();       
PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Capitales_totales SET capital_total = $capital_total + '"+value1+"';
```

What is the correct syntax for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using binds, e.g.

```
PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Capitales_totales SET capital_total = capital_total + ?");
pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(value1));
```

Note: `Integer.parseInt()` may throw RuntimeExpection

Comment: Thanks a lot that was it, i appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, datatype of the `capital_total` isn't provided. So, we'll assume that it's integer or numeric datatype.

MySQL syntax to add a value to the value that's already stored in a column, is something like this:

```
  UPDATE mytable 
     SET mycol = mycol + 20
   WHERE id = 1
```

If mycol contains a NULL value, then a NULL will be assigned.  (An unknown value 
plus 20 results in an unknown value.) If you want to handle a NULL value as if it were zero...

```
  UPDATE mytable 
     SET mycol = IFNULL(mycol,0) + 20
   WHERE id = 1
```

As far as how you do that in Java prepared statement, use a bind placeholder in place of the value in the SQL text, and then provide a value for the bind placeholder with the `setString` method.

```
String sql = "UPDATE mytable
                 SET mycol = IFNULL(mycol,0) + ?
               WHERE id = 1";
PreparedStmt pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

sample code snippet for the use-case:

```
PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("Update  Capitales_totales set capital_total =capital_total+?");
pst.setString(1, Integer.parseInt("int_string"));

OR

pst.setInt(1, 1001); //sample int 1001
```